# combining rows into list ordered by date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has several unique ID's and text.  I'm trying to combine the text ordered by date.

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+
| unique_id | date                | data |
+-----------+---------------------+------+
| 1         | 2010-05-19 21:30:27 | a    |
+-----------+---------------------+------+
| 1         |                     | b    |
|           | 2010-05-21 01:36:23 |      |
+-----------+---------------------+------+
| 1         |                     | c    |
|           | 2010-05-23 06:46:23 |      |
+-----------+---------------------+------+
```

Ideally, I am trying to combine the rows in data to a list, ordered by date.

Something like this:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| unique_id | date                                                             | data      |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 1         | [2010-05-19 21:30:27, 2010-05-21 01:36:23, 2010-05-23 06:46:23]  | [a, b, c] |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I am currently sorting the dataframe by date and then using group by to order the elements using the following:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort('date')
df = df.groupby(['unique_id']).agg(lambda x: set(tuple(x))).applymap(list).reset_index()
```

However, when grouping, the order of the data is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
df_tmp = df.groupby('unique_id', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: sorted(set(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `unique` in `pandas`

```
df.groupby('unique_id',sort=False).agg(lambda x : x.unique().tolist())
```

Comment: I suspect this'll have the same problem as the OP using a `set` here... since `Series.unique` says: *Uniques are returned in order of appearance. Hash table-based unique, therefore does NOT sort.* - which isn't the same as in order of the data - unless it's in date order already...

Answer (score 0):

Your `set` in your `.agg` isn't preserving order - if you need to remove duplicates then you can do something like:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['unique_id', 'date']).sort_values('date').groupby('unique_id').agg(list)
```